# What is a SQL Query to return count of rows per attribute in a date range?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a table named `PDA_COLLECTOR_SCCS` in an Access database where I would like to query the number of rows per `District` per `PickupDate`.  `District` is a string indicating the district of the client and the `PickupDate` is when the service order was completed.  `PickupDate` is in `mm/d/yyyy`format.  Starting with `10/1/2007` to `today`.

For instance, each month for each district should have an integer output, i.e. `DistrictName, EV` , `Date Range 10/1/2007 - 10/31/2007`, `RowCount, 564`

EDIT:
It is SQL Server 2008

`SELECT District, Convert(date, PickupDate) As PickUpMonth, Count(*) As Row_Count
FROM dbo.V_PickupAllColumns
GROUP BY District, Convert(date, PickupDate)`

[image]

This query returns the number of rows per day per district, how would I change this to return the number rows per month-to-month range, i.e. 10/1/2007-10/31/2007

Answer (score 0):

Use an aggregate query for any Count(), Sum(), Avg(), Max(), and Min() functions:

**Aggregate by District**

```
SELECT District, Count(*) As RowCount
FROM PDA_COLLECTOR_SCCS
GROUP BY District
```

**Aggregate by District, Month, Year**

And if you want by month, add it as another group by column. Below converts `PickUp` to indicate Month and Year.

```
SELECT District, CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), 
                         CAST(DATEPART(mm, PickUpDate) AS Varchar(2))) + '-' + 
                 CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),  
                         CAST(DATEPART(yyyy, PickUpDate) As Varchar(4))) As PickUpMonth, 
       Count(*) As [RowCount]
FROM PDA_COLLECTOR_SCCS
GROUP BY District, MONTH(PickUpDate), YEAR(PickUpDate)
```

**Aggregate with Date Range**

Now if you want a date range column, a derived table subquery can be used:

```
SELECT District, CONVERT(nvarchar(max), 
                         CAST(CAST(GroupYear AS varchar(4)) + '-' + 
                              CAST(GroupMonth AS varchar(2)) + '-' + 
                              CAST(1 AS varchar(1)) As DATETIME), 101) + ' - ' +
                 CONVERT(nvarchar(max), DateAdd(d, -1, DateAdd(mm, 1,  
                         CAST(CAST(GroupYear AS varchar(4)) + '-' + 
                              CAST(GroupMonth AS varchar(2)) + '-' + 
                              CAST(1 AS varchar(1)) As DATETIME))), 101) As PickUpRange, 
      [RowCount]
FROM (
      SELECT District, MONTH(PickUpDate) As GroupMonth, 
                       YEAR(PickUpDate) As GroupYear, 
             Count(*) As [RowCount]
      FROM PDA_COLLECTOR_SCCS
      GROUP BY District, MONTH(PickUpDate), YEAR(PickUpDate)
     ) As derivedTable
```

Comment: When I execute this in SQL Server Management Studio 2008, I receive the error `'Format' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Comment: It was added to Sql Server beginning with Sql Server 2014. If you need something older than the current version, remember to specify the version in your tags.

Comment: Your post's very top line mentioned Access database which uses `Format()`. I have now edited for SQL Server and to include date range column.